# Clearing drawableLeft (NOT background) when user clicks autoCompleteEditText

Tags: java, android

I have a search icon on the left side of my editText by utilizing the "drawableLeft" attribute in the xml. I want that search icon to be removed when the user presses the editText and reappear when he deselects it. I have seen many threads talking about utilizing this code
'''

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

'''

but this seems to get rid of ALL my drawables, including my background drawable. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();
setCompoundDrawables(null, drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3]);
```

The order that the drawables are passed in is left, top, right, and bottom.